# Oculus Rift Multiplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, photon, unity3d-unet

We are working on a VR collaboration app where user imports CAD files at run time. Then different users perform operations on it together. We are using Unity.

The challenges:
1. CAD files are very large.
2. Our app has desktop as well as Oculus Rift mode.

Which multiplayer approach should we follow? I heard that OculusPlatform sdk has support for generic networking also. Should we go for it, or rather choose from UNet and Photon?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I made a simple game for GearVR (oculus) with Unet, and it wasn't very difficult. So if you know how Unet works, you can try the Unet approach ^^

Comment: Hi Lotan, thanks for sharing your experience. GearVR doesn't support avatar. Do you know anyone who worked on Oculus Rift multiplayer with large files imported at runtime?

Comment: Avatar? which Avatar? if you are talking about Oculus Avatar SDK, GearVR supports it: https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-avatar-sdk/ (or at least it seems)